# How to reduce Wordpress post loading time (Single post)

Tags: php, wordpress, time, response, loading

I have some post in the wordpress website which has a lot of content. I have a post which is taking 30-35 second to load. Content of that page is coming from a single post and includes lot of shortcodes. Problem is I am not able to reduce the loading time which is most challenging for me. I used custom lazy loader but no luck. Any suggestions/recommendation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to know if we don't know what code you have or what plugins you use

Comment: start with pulling out the shortcodes and putting them back in one by one. You'll find out wether or not and if so which of the shortcodes is causing the problem.

Comment: I have used multiple plugins like : amazon, custom plugin i created. 
custom jquery for lazy loader. 
I created a plugin but it is only taking 10second. so there is no issue with that plugin. Problem is when I am loading all post content in a single time.

Comment: I do same Giorgio, I know which one is creating the problem,  but i need all shortcode there :).

Comment: Sorry... You don't find it an issue that a plugin takes 10 seconds? I'm not used to wordpress. I have only used when "forced to", but 10 seconds is a lot! My weather page that has around 11000 lines of code loads on less than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem by improving the code. There was some problem in amazon api which we created it. And if you hit amazon server again and again it will block your ip address. So to prevent for that there was sleep() function added which send the request to amazon after few second. I remove that one and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First off I suggest using a CDN. A good one that I use is [Stackpath](https://www.stackpath.com/pricing/)
Then I would also use [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/l)

Finally and once signed up for these 2 I would follow this 2017 updated [blog post](http://www.onlinemediamasters.com/w3-total-cache-settings/)

Another suggestion is to install the [kraken.io](https://kraken.io/) plugin and signup for this as well buddy.

All of these together will speed up the entire website.